# How to remove support from other Android Play Store form factors?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, android-manifest, google-play-console

My app doesn't use any special play features and I want it to be available only for Android Phones.
This is the initial supported device list.
I tried first to add `android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"` but it removed 250 phones and only ~ 2000 tablets. It removed the car and chromebooks, but still somehow kept 1 TV.

Adding `support-screens` did absolutely nothing to change the form factor availability.
I wish to do this programatically, because I don't want to edit the device catalog manually on every release

[image]